# check submit button id and execute different function

Tags: angularjs

in my form, i am using two submit buttons. when i submit the button, first need to check button id and execute function accordingly. please check my code.

```js
$scope.saveme = function(user,data) {

alert(id);
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" ng-submit="saveme(user,data)">
Name : <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
Age : <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"/>

<button type="submit" id="s" data="{{button.id}}"> Save</button>
<button type="submit" id="ss" data="{{button.id}}">Save with Exit </button>
</form>
```

actually i need to alert button id that i clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$scope.saveme = function(user,exit) {
  if(exit){
     //do something
  }else{
     //do something else
 } 
 alert(id);
```

}

```
<form name="myform">
     Name : <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
     Age : <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"/>

     <button type="submit" id="s" ng-click="saveme(user,false)"> Save</button>
     <button type="submit" id="ss" ng-click="sameme(user,true)">Save with Exit</button>
 </form>
```

You will know which button was clicked checking the exit param value

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below code.

if your first button return true second button will not trigger if your second button return false second button will trigger.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <form name="myform">
Name : <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
Age : <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"/>

<button type="submit" id="s" ng-click="saveme(1) || saveme1()" > Save</button>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>



<script>
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.saveme = function(user) {
   if(user === 1){  
   alert('first button');
   return false
   } else {
   alert('first button fails');
    return true;

}
};
$scope.saveme1 = function(user,data) {

alert('second button');
};
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="saveme(user,data)">
Name : <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
Age : <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"/>

<button type="submit" id="s" ng-click="save('s')"> Save</button>
<button type="submit" id="ss" ng-click=saveExit"('ss')" >Save with Exit </button>
</form>

$scope.saveExit = function(val)
{
alert(val);
}
$scope.save= function(val)
{
alert(val);
}
```

Comment: i need to use single save function.

Comment: you can name saveExit as save and add Parameter something like this save('s','saveonly');   save('ss','saveExit');